Using an Irish passport in the EU but my wife only has a UK passport
I have just received my Irish passport. My wife has a UK passport. If I stay in an EU country for 90 days then leave and return straight away, can my wife also do this? Do I need documentation of any sort?

I am in the same position: I am dual UK / Irish and my wife is UK only.  I have had mixed experience using this right.  A few years ago in Copenhagen, I tried to take her through the EU queue with me and I was told: "we don't do that here".  More recently, in Amsterdam, we went to separate queues and she was told off for not going through with me.

@badjohn They were wrong both in Copenhagen and Amsterdam. Schengen Border Code Article 10 2. Persons enjoying the right of free movement under Union law are entitled to use the lanes indicated by the sign shown in Part A (‘EU, EEA, CH’) of Annex III. They may also use the lanes indicated by the sign shown in Part B1 (‘visa not required’) and Part B2 (‘all passports’) of Annex III. This includes Family Members.

@MarkJohnson I am not saying that either was right or wrong, just what I experienced.  I did not make a fuss in Copenhagen as the non-EU queue was not long and we did not plan to stay long.  In Amsterdam, I was not there when my wife was told off but she was told to go through with me next time.

@MarkJohnson: Why what that matter? In my experience immigration, customs & security offices often don't give a hoot what's right or wrong: they do whatever they feel like doing. They know they are in a position of power and that the traveler has little or no recourse. Pointing out to an officer that they are not following the rules typically does NOT end well.

As a non EU-citizen (but a resident (not PR)) I often use the EU lines because they're shorter/faster, no one ever complains because the process to let me in is maybe only 10 seconds longer than a citizen (because they need to scan both my passport and my residence permit, but no further questions are asked, my passport is not stamped per schengen code) but way faster than a tourist (which can take several minutes). Outside EU there's been times where I was routed to all passports queue even though I was citizen (because line was shorter), sometimes even to the diplomatic passport line.

@badjohn With that in mind, it is very weird that Copenhagen complained, especially as the process of letting her in is allowed by schengen code and is not significantly longer than letting a union citizen couple (especially if you share a last name and have your proof of marriage ready in case it is requested).

@ave I did not argue the point.  As Hilmar says, arguing with immigration staff is generally not a good idea.  Especially so in this case as none of the queues were long and our visit was expected to be within the limits of UK citizens in general.  My guess is that they simply did not know the process.   A possible explanation is that it was someone managing the queue who stopped us.  She was probably not an immigration officer herself.  Maybe if we had managed to get to the desk, my wife might have been accepted.

@badjohnn And maybe you should have thought of that before you wrote first comment (where you wrote 'we' impling an official person - and the later stating you really don't know who 'we' was). Such vauge, misleading, comments are the source of hearsay 'knowlage'.

@MarkJohnson I don't think that I was unclear or misleading.  A member of staff in uniform stopped us.  I just don't know the qualifications of that person.  It was not another passenger who told us "we don't do that here".

@badjohnn A member of staff of what? (that you obviously don't know). This is a question about immigration law, not about the lack of knowlage of a (possibly) auxiliary staff. As stated such vauge, misleading, comments are the source of hearsay 'knowlage'.

@MarkJohnson It was only a comment and not an answer.  Others can read all of these comments, yours and mine, and judge what, if any, value to accord to my story.  Whoever the person was, it was a real obstacle to bringing my wife to the EU queue.  It is something that others attempting to do this may face.

@badjohnn (for others) you would have saved yourself a lot of bother had you required that a official person, knowlagable in the relavent law, be called. In my experience, all objections then disappear.

@MarkJohnson As I explained already, I did not make a fuss as the non-EU queue was short and we would not be staying long.  So, there was very little bother with accepting it.  Had the non-EU queue been long or we wanted to stay a long time, I would have queried the matter.


If I stay in an eu country for 90 days then leave and return straight away can my wife also do this?

Provided they are traveling with you or going to join you, yes, your freedom of movement as a EU citizen extends to your partner (and also to unmarried -21 children), and the Schengen clock will not run if you're with them.

Do I need documentation of any sort?

You will want to have the proof of marriage in hand if married, but you are unlikely to be asked for it.

traveling with you or to reunite with you

travelling with me

@PaulWaring MJeffryes wasn't asking you a question, but clarifying that the freedom of movement extends both to someone travelling with their EU spouse and someone travelling to reunite with their EU spouse.


If I stay in an eu country for 90 days then leave and return straight away can my wife also do this?

Yes. Whether simply 'hopping over the border and then immediately back' will be considered as an absence, interrupting the 3-month period, will depend on the registration laws of the specific country.
Whatever form a specific country may require (if any) as registration for stays longer than 3 months in a single EU country, your non-EU spouse would be included in that registration.
As the spouse of an EU citizen, when accompanying or joining the EU citizen, the spouse may utilise the same Freedom of Movement rights as the EU citizen.

Do I need documentation of any sort?

A marriage certificate should be sufficient.

Thankyou for the information
